# "A tool to do" vs. "a tool that does" vs. "a tool for doing"

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, prepositions, infinitives, gerunds

I'm the curator of the Open Web Platform Daily Digest [link](http://webplatformdaily.org/). In the "Tools" section of each daily I write entries in this format:

- tool_name, tool_description

For example:

- hapi, a server framework for Node.js

My question is, which of these should I use:

- ClippingMagic, an online tool *to remove* image backgrounds
- ClippingMagic, an online tool *for removing* image backgrounds
- ClippingMagic, an online tool *that removes* image backgrounds

(That tool is located [here](http://clippingmagic.com/) btw.)

Comment: I'd say *for removing*, because a tool presumably doesn't act on its own - it surely requires *some* degree of instruction and supervision. But really and truly, I don't think it matters. They all work.

Comment: All three are acceptable and mean nearly the same thing. Use the appropriate alternative depending on the rest of the sentence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think first two options will be better as the third option somewhat implies that ClippingMagic is an automated tool, i.e. it works without any human intervention. 
So if it is an automated tool then go for third option otherwise go for any of the first two options.

Hope it helps